# substitution within fields perl

Tags: regex, perl, join, split

I need to parse through many delimited files and I had a question.  Within a while loop, how do I make a substitution within a field?  Let me give some example code and data.

Data Example:

```
Word,Name,Number,You/Me,Data
Hello,Josh,123,Me,Data
Hello,Joe,222,Me,Data
```

GOAL:

In this example what I would like to do is do a substitution on $[2] and $[3].

In other words, the field $[2] would be the number field.  $[3] would be the You/Me field.

What I have in my code is this:

```
my @F = split;

while (<>) {
    if ($F[3] =~ /^You$/ print "Me";) next;
    if ($F[2] =~ /^222$/ print "P";) next;
    if ($F[2] =~ /^123$/ print "P";) next;
    print @F;
}
```

I can't seem to find the correct syntax to make substitutions in specific fields and was hoping someone would have a suggestion.  The goal of my results is below.

DESIRED RESULTS:

```
Word,Name,Number,You/Me,Data
Hello,Josh,P,Me,Data
Hello,Joe,P,Me,Data
```

I would just like to perform substitutions on the fields specified and leave everything else the same.

Additionally I may have a scenario where I would like to delimit certain fields by something completely different while leaving everything else the same.  I would also like to use scalars.

Data Example:

```
Word,Name,Number,You/Me,Data
Hello,Josh,123,Me,Data
Hello,Joe,222,Me,Data
```

DESIRED RESULTS:

```
Word,Name,Number,You/Me,Data
Hello,Josh,P-Me,Data
Hello,Joe,P-Me,Data
```

EXAMPLE with scalar

```
my $numbers = qw/222|123/;
    my @F = split;

    while (<>) {
        if ($F[3] =~ /^You$/ print "Me";) next;
        if ($F[2] = /^$numbers$/ print "P";) next;
        join ("-",$[2],$[3]);
        print @F;
    }
```

So in the end, I would like to know how to substitute in fields, join specific fields with a different delimiter, and implement scalars into this sort of split/join script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `perl` script does what you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = "file";

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';

my $numbers = qr/^(?:222|123)$/;
while (<>) {
    print and next if /^\s+$/ or $.==1;
    my @flds = split /,/;
    $flds[2] = "P" if $flds[2] =~ $numbers; 
    $flds[3] = "Me" if $flds[3] eq "You";  
    print join ",", @flds[0,1], join ("-", @flds[2,3]), @flds[4..$#flds];
}

#unlink "$file$^I";
```

#### Outputs:

```
Word,Name,Number,You/Me,Data

Hello,Josh,P-Me,Data

Hello,Joe,P-Me,Data
```

We use `$^I` variable to do in-place changes while creating a backup of the original with extension of `.bak`. We split the line on `,` and populate an array called `@flds`.

Then we do two checks and if they are successful we make the changes to the fields. Once the checks are done we print the array which has the modified fields for every successful test.

`unlink` is commented out. You can uncomment it if you don't want back up file.

You can remove `print and next unless /\S/;` line if you do not have any blank lines in your file or if you do not wish to retain them in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to change "You" to "Me"? Your desired results show you won't like to change, but you code is otherwise.

I think you can use `$F[2] =~ s/^123$/P/`. See `perldoc perlre`

And maybe you would like to use `$^I` variable if you want in-place edition.
See `perldoc perlval`